# Including multiple params returns zsh parse error?

Tags: node.js, curl

This works:

```
curl -d parent_account=smartsneakers -d account_name=KC -d platform=insta -d first_name=Kramer -d last_name=Hardbody -d campaigns_sub=Simple -d campaign_payments=5 -d payments_accrued=50 -d lifetime_payouts=10 -d payments_refunded=0 -d payment_blocked=false -d kyc_completed=true http://localhost:3000/parentRoute
```

This doesn't:

```
curl --data “parent_account=smartsneakers&account_name=KC&platform=insta&first_name=Kramer& last_name=Hardbody&campaigns_sub=Simple&campaign_payments=5&payments_accrued=50&lifetime_payouts=10&payments_refunded=0&payment_blocked=false&kyc_completed=true” http://localhost:3000/parentRoute
```

I get the following error: zsh: parse error near `&'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use actual ascii double quotes (ascii code 34), and not the Unicode 8220 ones:

```
curl --data "parent_account=smartsneakers&account_name=KC&platform=insta&first_name=Kramer& last_name=Hardbody&campaigns_sub=Simple&campaign_payments=5&payments_accrued=50&lifetime_payouts=10&payments_refunded=0&payment_blocked=false&kyc_completed=true" http://localhost:3000/parentRoute
```